# Kubernets (k3s) kubectl acces through reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, reverse-proxy, kubectl, k3s

I'm running a Kubernetes (k3s) server on a raspberry pi cluster locally, which then is connect to a VM on digital ocean via a VPN (Tailscale), I've successfuly manage to make reverse proxy to my services on the cluster using nginx, but when I want to point a domain to my kube api server it just keep getting unauthorized responses.

In my Nginx config I've set it up something like this:

```
server {
    server_name kube.domain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://xx.xx.xx.xx:6433;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

I'm using kubectl setting my server to: `kube.comain.com`

And here I get the 401, but if i set the server to my ip on the localhost it works fine, so im wondering why do I get a 401, since I clearly contact my Kube API Server.

Answer (score 0):

Nginx Reverse proxy by default strips the certifcate data that kubectl sends with the request and there for the request will end up with at 401.

Solution should be to create a raw TCP stream targeting the IP of the kubernetes api server minimal example like so:

**nginx.conf**

```
stream {
        upstream api {
                server <kube-api-server-ip>:6443;
        }
        server {
                listen <port>; # this is the port exposed by nginx on your proxy server
                proxy_pass api;
                proxy_timeout 20s;
        }
}
```

Doing the above would proxy the raw request directly to the kube-apiserver.

more detailed answer can be found here both TCP L4 layer and L7 layer solutions: https://www.henryxieblogs.com/2021/12/how-to-expose-kube-api-server-via-nginx.html